# WPF - how to interface with a usercontrol in a stackpanel/itemscontrol in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I'm not really sure how to ask this question, so please tell me what I need to clarify!

I want to make a collection of identical structures, including a usercontrol and a remove button, and store them in a List of something.

```
| <Some UserControl> | <Button> | <= grid   <= this is an ItemsTemplate instance
| <Some UserControl> | <Button> | <= grid
| <Some UserControl> | <Button> | <= grid
```

I can get this working without the extra level of 'grid' that having a remove button adds... but once I add a grid, there seems to be a disconnect between my data model and the screen (ie, I can't pull data out of the usercontrols).

My main window has this helper class, and my UserControl is just called PathThing. It's in another pair of files, but I don't think that's relevant to my problem.

I think my issue is that the PathThing in PathEntry does not become related to the UserControl displayed.

```
// I want this to represent 1 entry in the ItemsControl (DataTemplate instance)
public partial class PathEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private PathThing m_path = new PathThing();

    public PathThing  Path
    {
        get
        {
            return m_path;
        }
        set
        {
            m_path = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow has these members:

```
    #region Paths
    private ObservableCollection<PathEntry> m_things = new ObservableCollection<PathEntry>();
    public ObservableCollection<PathEntry> PThings
    {
        get
        {
            return m_things;
        }
        set
        {
            m_things = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

And the Xaml is this

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="5" 
              Name="CPaths"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PThings, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <local:PathThing Grid.Column="0" Question="What Do I write here to make this bind to PathEntry.Path?"></local:PathThing>
                <Button Grid.Column="1">Remove</Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What is the definition of a PathThing? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Gui a PathThing is some userControl, created by right clicking on the project and adding a new UserControl. It has a XAML and a .cs file - I don't have a lot in it, but it might include, say, some entry fields. What I want to achieve is to be able to have the list of PathEntry "connected" to PathThings in some way, and access their public properties or something similar.

Comment: You should declare [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties) in your UserControl that can be bound to view model properties, like `<local:PathThing MyProperty="{Binding PathEntry.Path}">`.

Comment: It might be simpler not having a PathThing at all, and just using a DataTemplate for your PathEntry.

Comment: That would be simpler, but then it's harder to reuse and it bloats one file... but maybe that's ok. @Gui
How do I set the datacontext of a dynamically created element? 
I want to do something like... 
ItemsControl[0].Grid.PathThing.DataContext = this... but that's a bit horrible because it couples the code to the Xaml structure...
edit: oh hang on, can I put a DataTemplate in another file as a resource?

Comment: Yes, you can put a DataTemplate in another file; just make a resource dictionary, put your DataTemplate; make sure you specify a target type for your DataTemplate. Simply add it to a merged dictionary to apply it.
You can set the DataContext for items in your XAML if you wish, but you will encounter problems sooner or later without getting a deeper understanding of how WPF works. Dependency Properties are a repeatable alternative.
Worry less about coupling C# to XAML, focus on separating concerns. Think of code behind as an extension of XAML; The ViewModel should be decoupled.